# Why does TypeScript allow me to omit the return type of a function?

Tags: typescript

I have noImplicitAny set to true in my tsconfig. So I was surprised when it allowed me to omit function return types. I have a getter function that looks like this:

```
get name() {
    return `${this.valueName} of ${this.suitName}`;
}
```

Q1: What is the return type of the name() getter? Is it any?

Q2: And if it's any, why is this allowed given that I have noImplicitAny set to true?

Answer (score 2):

noImplictAny configuration forces you to define a type where TypeScript can't infer it. For instance:

```
let x;
function f(a) {
   x = a;
}
```

There is no way here TypeScript can know for sure which type should be `a` or `x`. Here the compiler would warn you about using any implicitly.

In this code:

```
get name() {
   return `${this.valueName} of ${this.suitName}`;
}
```

TypeScript can infer here you are returning a `string`.

Note that you don't have to define every argument or variable. That would be pedantic, in cases such as:

```
// Verbose
const x : string = "hi";
// Compact yet enough
const x = "hi";
```